# Triggers to automatically update column in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in PostgreSQL where I added a new column which is a concatenation of 2 columns that already exists in the table. I am able to use concat function and added values to that column for all the existing data in the table. the issue is now when I want to add more data to that table from txt file it gives me error: missing data for column "xzy ".

To resolve this issue I tried making triggers so that every time a file is uploaded it will automatically concat and add data to that new column "xyz". So far I have been unsuccessful.

CREATE and ADD   Throughput_Worktype field in main_ WC4:

```
ALTER TABLE wc4  ADD COLUMN throughput_wrktype VARCHAR(50);

UPDATE wc4 SET throughput_wrktype = concat(trim('' from wrktype), '-', replace (unitcd,'-','' ));
```

Create Trigger for values to be automatically updated in throughput_worktype column everytime new file is uploaded :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION befo_insert()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
NEW.throughput_wrktype = concat(trim('' from new.wrktype),   '-', replace (new.unitcd,'-','' ));
RETURN NEW;
END;

$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER concat_before_update
  BEFORE  update
  ON wc4
  FOR EACH ROW          EXECUTE PROCEDURE befo_insert();
```

Comment: Try `trim(new.wrktype)` instead of `trim('' from new.wrktype)` in the trigger function

Comment: That didn't make any difference

Comment: That should not be an issue as I am able to use concat and get the desired output. I just cannot automate the process so when ever I upload new file it does it automatically instead of giving error of missing data in that extra column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need. I created a table and fill it for testing. Adopt the code to your needs. Use your function for filling the fields of the third column (I used only simple concat). You might need to add a trigger and function for updating records in your table.

```
-- create a table 'some_table'
CREATE TABLE some_table(
   column1 VARCHAR (16) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
   column2 VARCHAR (16) NOT NULL
   );

-- fill the table with some data
INSERT INTO some_table VALUES ('a', '00001');
INSERT INTO some_table VALUES ('b', '00002');

-- look what's in the table
SELECT * FROM some_table;

 column1 | column2 
---------+---------
 a       | 00001
 b       | 00002
(2 rows)

-- add the third column 'column3' and populate it 
ALTER TABLE some_table ADD COLUMN column3 VARCHAR(35);
UPDATE some_table SET column3= CONCAT(column1, ' - ', column2);

--take look in the table
SELECT * FROM some_table;

 column1 | column2 |  column3  
---------+---------+-----------
 a       | 00001   | a - 00001
 b       | 00002   | b - 00002
(2 rows)

-- create function that update table after each inserting into 'some_table'
CREATE FUNCTION some_table_insert() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  UPDATE some_table SET column3 = concat(NEW.column1,  ' - ', NEW.column2) WHERE column1 = NEW.column1;
  RETURN new;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- create trigger that calls function 'some_table_insert' after each insert into "some_table"
CREATE TRIGGER some_table_insert_trigger AFTER INSERT ON some_table FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE some_table_insert();

-- insert into the table
INSERT INTO some_table VALUES ('c', '00003');

-- see the result
SELECT * FROM some_table;

 column1 | column2 |  column3  
---------+---------+-----------
 a       | 00001   | a - 00001
 b       | 00002   | b - 00002
 c       | 00003   | c - 00003
(3 rows)
```

Now the data in the table are duplicated but that is what you wanted.